# configuring commons DBCP with tomcat 6.0 and java 1.6

Tags: java, database, tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp

I want to use commons DBCP in my web application. I am using java 1.6 and tomcat 6.0 .
I really don't know how to configure DBCP as i am going to use it for the first
time in my life.
Can someone tell me how to configure the dbcp ?  I need detailed steps for cofiguration.
also i would like to know how to access the connection in servlet after configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [Instructions](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) It should be sufficient.